# How does this aggregation works in the Kafka stream?

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new to the Apache Kafka. I read the code of a steam application and stumbled upon the aggregation operation. I try to understand it on my own and I need the confirmation if I'm being correct to interpret.

The code snippet to read from the topic and aggregation is provided below,

```
// json Serde
final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);


KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

// read from the topic 'bank-transactions' as `KStream`. I provided the producer below 
KStream<String, JsonNode> bankTransactions = builder.stream(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde, "bank-transactions");

// we define the grouping and aggregation here 
KTable<String, JsonNode> bankBalance = bankTransactions.groupByKey(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde)
    .aggregate(
            () -> initialBalance,
            (key, transaction, balance) -> newBalance(transaction, balance),
            jsonSerde,
            "bank-balance-agg"
    );
```

The stream of data to the `bank-transactions` topic is produced as follows,

```
public static ProducerRecord<String, String> newRandomTransaction(String name) {
    // creates an empty json {}
    ObjectNode transaction = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

    Integer amount = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100);

    // Instant.now() is to get the current time using Java 8
    Instant now = Instant.now();

    // we write the data to the json document
    transaction.put("name", name);
    transaction.put("amount", amount);
    transaction.put("time", now.toString());

    return new ProducerRecord<>("bank-transactions", name, transaction.toString());
}
```

The initial balance is initiated as follows,

```
// create the initial json object for balances
ObjectNode initialBalance = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

initialBalance.put("count", 0);
initialBalance.put("balance", 0);
initialBalance.put("time", Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L).toString());
```

The `newBalance` method takes a transaction and balance and returns the new balance,

```
private static JsonNode newBalance(JsonNode transaction, JsonNode balance) {
    // create a new balance json object
    ObjectNode newBalance = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

    newBalance.put("count", balance.get("count").asInt() + 1);
    newBalance.put("balance", balance.get("balance").asInt() + transaction.get("amount").asInt());

    Long balanceEpoch = Instant.parse(balance.get("time").asText()).toEpochMilli();
    Long transactionEpoch = Instant.parse(transaction.get("time").asText()).toEpochMilli();

    Instant newBalanceInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Math.max(balanceEpoch, transactionEpoch));
    newBalance.put("time", newBalanceInstant.toString());

    return newBalance;
}
```

I have 2 questions about the grouping and aggregation,

a. Is the `groupByKey` is grouping by the `Serdes.String()` and the `jsonSerde` is only performing the serialization and deserialization for the steam data?  The `Serdes.String()` is a name String in the `newRandomTransaction` method.

b. My assertion is the `key, transaction` inside the `aggregation` function of the line `(key, transaction, balance) -> newBalance(transaction, balance)`  is read from the `bank-transactions` topic and the `balance` is coming from the `initialBalance` from the previous line. Is that correct?

I also puzzled while trying to debug the app though it runs seamlessly.

Comment: I'm sure that my understanding here it pretty naive but this is the first time I work with the Kafka (also the stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the groupByKey is grouping by the Serdes.String() and the jsonSerde is only performing the serialization and deserialization for the steam data?

Yes, groupByKey is grouping by the keys, which are able to be deserialized and compared as strings

> My assertion is the key, transaction inside the aggregation function of the line (key, transaction, balance) -> newBalance(transaction, balance) is read from the bank-transactions topic and the balance is coming from the initialBalance from the previous line

Almost. The initializer is on the first parameter, yes, but the aggregated result is carried forward throughout the entire execution of the application, endlessly aggregating.

In other words, you start with `initialBalance` always, then for every key that's the same, you add that `transaction`'s balance to the currently accumulated `balance` for that key. If you have not yet seen the key repeated, only then will it be added to the initial balance

And yes, your input topic was specified by the KStreams `builder.stream` method

Comment: Maybe an example would help? Also note, that a repartition topic is only create if necessary -- for the code snippet in the question, repartitioning would not be required.

Comment: hi cricket_007, I understand your answer and accepted it.  But, some example will do better as in my humble opinion, the docs for the Kafka is required to be better.

Comment: @Matthias I'll leave the example up to you ;)

Comment: @Yoda If you think that the docs are insufficient, please contribute to AK and open a PR to improve the docs!